# Php and sqlite3 problems with DELETE

Tags: php, sqlite

I've been learning PHP with a course of a page called Video2Brain, the problem is that the course was made with SQLite2 and MAMP or XAMP not work me with this version, in SQLite3 gives me error many times the query, but I managed to solve the many of them, except the part where you ask me use the DELETE. Here are the data fails I used to see if they can somehow help me.

```
   //index.php 
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = "carlos";
    $_SESSION['pass'] = "carlos";
    echo '
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=principal.php">
    </head>
    </html>'
    ?>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    //first.php
<?php
session_start();
echo "Tu usuario es: ".$_SESSION['usuario']."<br />";
echo "Tu password es: ".$_SESSION['pass'];
$conexion = new SQLite3('favoritosbase.db');
$consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM favoritos WHERE usuario='carlos' AND pass='carlos';");
echo "
<table border=1 width=100%>
<tr>
<td><STRONG>Titulo</STRONG></td>
<td><STRONG>Link</STRONG></td>
<td><STRONG>Categoria</STRONG></td>
<td><STRONG>Comentario</STRONG></td>
<td><STRONG>Valoracion</STRONG></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
";
while($fila = $consulta->fetchArray()){
echo "<tr><td>".$fila['titulo']."</td><td>".$fila['url']."</td><td>".$fila['categoria']."</td><td>".$fila['comentario']."</td><td>".$fila['valoracion']."</td><td><a href='eliminarfavorito.php?titulo=".$fila['titulo']."&url=".$fila['url']."&categoria=".$fila['categoria']."&comentario=".$fila['comentario']."&valoracion=".$fila['valoracion']."'>Eliminar</a></td></tr>";
}
echo "
<tr>
<form action='crearfavorito.php' method='post'>
<td><input type='text' name='titulo'></td>
<td><input type='text' name='url'></td>
<td><select name='categoria'>
<option value='salud'>Salud</option>
<option value='trabajo'>Trabajo</option>
<option value='hobby'>Hobby</option>
<option value='personal'>Personal</option>
<option value='otros'>Otros</option>
</td>
<td><input type='text' name='comentario'></td>
<td><input type='text' name='valoracion'></td>
<td><input type='submit'></td>
</tr>
</table>"
?>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//delete.php
    <?php
    session_start();
    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    $pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
    $titulo = $_GET['titulo'];
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $categoria = $_GET['categoria'];
    $comentario = $_GET['comentario'];
    $valoracion = $_GET['valoracion'];
    $conexion = new SQLite3('favoritosbase.db');
    $conexion->exec("DELETE FROM favoritos WHERE usuario=$usuario AND pass=$pass AND titulo=$titulo AND url=$url categoria=$categoria AND comentario=$comentario AND valoracion=$valoracion");
    $conexion->close();
    ?>
```

Excuse variables and the data is in Spanish, I'm speaking for that reason, but I hope you can help me, I think the problem is in delete.php, if they know how to solve, help me.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is, or what is the error message you're receiving? It's hard for us to figure out a solution when we don't know the problem.

Comment: @ChristianVarga The problem is that the app should record data and to delete only records but when I try to delete, does not.

Comment: You appear to have a syntax error: `AND url=$url categoria=$categoria` should be `AND url=$url AND categoria=$categoria`.

Comment: @ChristianVarga Apparently this was a mistake but not the mistake that leaves me delete the data, but thanks